# npm react-select-async-paginate: How to test?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

**Question: How to UX test `npm react-select-async-paginate`?**

Great module, and great results.

Before switching out `<select>` component for the `react-select-async-paginate` component, testing involved:

- navigate to `<select>` using CSS selectors
- verify all expected `<option>`(s)
- select a specific `<option>` either by attribute
- verify option was selected

Not obvious how to do the same level of testing with this react component.

**Example usage of react-select-async-paginate:**

[image: react-select-async-paginate in action]

DevTools inspection shows nothing to navigate using CSS selectors to validate runtime usage of this component.

Suggestions welcomed.

Thank you